# How to use config variable in an external JavaScript file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework for one of my project. All is going well for me. I have set a config variable in

> application/config/config.php

file. How I did that? Have a look below

```
$config['my_key'] = 'abcdef123';
```

The issue is when I am trying to use this variable in an external JavaScript file, it is not putting the value there instead of putting all source. The code I used to get the value in JavaScript file is

```
var mykey = "<?php echo $this->config->item('my_key'); ?>";
```

but it is not showing the `my_key` value, but showing

```
<?php echo $this->config->item('my_key'); ?>
```

as it is. So how can I achieve the config value in external JavaScript file? I have included the JavaScript file using my controller.

Comment: When you say "External JS File" Are you using a <script scr=""....></script>  to include it or are you including it in the view itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can define this global variable above external js like describe below so you can achieve your goal.

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var mykey = "<?php echo $this->config->item('my_key'); ?>";
     </script>
     <script src="path/to/external/js/other.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now in external js you can use above variable value.

**other.js**

```
var key = mykey;
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: I am going to answer the same 1up for my side.